# Visual Studio 2012 how to get missing assembly references

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to c# and visual studio..

currently i'm developing a metro application fro windows 8 that works as a proxy switcher application..

when I using this code

**System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.Select = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxyURI);**

it says GlobalProxySelection does not exist in the System.Net.... I imported system.net at the begining of the code..

**Edit**
no problem with System.net... no errors showing at there..  But the thing is I cant use "GlobalProxySelection" and "WebProxy" classes..

Also Target framework is locked in application properties..

Comment: you need to learn to distinguish between imports and references. Imports are a convenience to allow you to use types without specifying their full names. But references are what tells the compiler about what types might be relevant.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you're building a Metro app, not a full-blown .NET framework one. It would be worth mentioning that in your question. Also, note that what you're trying to set is marked as obsolete in .NET framework, so its not surprising if its not available in Metro. Maybe if you asked the actual question "how do I set the default proxy for a metro app?", you'd get some more useful answers.

Comment: my mistake... thankz 4 tellin.. I edited my question..

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you haven't added a reference to the `System.Net` assembly. [See this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from MSDN which should give you more info on adding this reference.

Comment: no problem with System.net... no errors showing at there..  But the thing is I cant use "GlobalProxySelection" and "WebProxy" classes..

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Net` namespace is in the **system.dll** assembly.  I would be surprised if that weren't already referenced when you started the project, but to be safe, you should ensure that a reference to this dll exists.  If it doesn't, then add it.

You can always find this kind of information on MSDN: [GlobalProxySelection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.globalproxyselection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In the Inheritance Hierarchy section, there is namespace/assembly info.

The only other thing I can think of is maybe you've added a reference to some other assembly that has this namespace (seems unlikely, but possible).

Comment: no problem with System.net... no errors showing at there..  But the thing is I cant use "GlobalProxySelection" and "WebProxy" classes..

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your project's properties, what is your target framework? It might be that is's accidentally using the "Client Profile" version of the framework, which misses quite a few bits and pieces. If so, change it to the normal version and then it might suddenly exist.

Comment: I can't see the target framework..
img248.imageshack.us/img248/8694/38025896.jpg

Comment: It's odd that it's not available. Have a look at this to see if some setting is wrong maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998988/why-is-the-target-framework-dropdown-empty-and-greyed-out-in-my-c-sharp-class-li

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `Target Framework` on `Application section` and `don't fix to Client Profile`

[image]

Comment: I can't edit that.. It's locked..
screenshot: http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/8694/38025896.jpg