# Can't select .net framework in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015. When I tried to create a new web project, it doesn't allow me to select the target .net framework

[Image for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qsHp.png)

Comment: Might or might not help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11098601/11683, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2998988/11683.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing .NET framework?

Comment: yes i have re-installed

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen, you need to set an environment variable `DNX_IIS_RUNTIME_FRAMEWORK` to the target framework you want to use. You can do this in the Project Properties page for the web application, on the Debug tab. Just choose the `IIS Express` profile and add the environment variable as below:

[image]