# Cannot Change Target Framework?

Tags: c#

I came across this problem this morning that I can't change the target framework of an open source project. The Target framework option drop down is inactive/disabled. How to make it to work with .NET Framework 2.0?

This is the download link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.10.html

By the way, possible duplicate question? The "Another Question" that had linked is for VS2008. I'm using VS2017, and today's date is 2018. The linked question is about 10 years old. Things changed a lot in 10 years. The solutions provided in that link is almost inapplicable.

[image: Cannot Change Target Framework]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Target Framework dropdown empty and greyed out in my C# class library, VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998988/why-is-the-target-framework-dropdown-empty-and-greyed-out-in-my-c-sharp-class-li)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A modern class library should use multiple target frameworks today, which means the options can only be set in project files right now,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net40;net45</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Visual Studio does not yet have suitable UI elements to reflect the options, and that's why it is showed the way you saw.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Microsoft simply makes `<TargetFrameworks>` a hidden treasure. You cannot assume a single item in `<TargetFrameworks>` is equivalent to `<TargetFramework>`. No, it isn't. Even if I wrote Visual Studio, I would have done the same to make my code simple.

Comment: It is still not possible to manage multiple frameworks in the newest Visual Studio 2019, released some days ago. You have to do that manually. Take care about a single entry in `<TargetFramework>` and multiple entries in `<TargetFrameworks>` <- with ending 's'!

Comment: But why some project can, while some project cannot?

Comment: @liang Open the project files you were referring to in text editor and compare them. Cannot be simpler to learn why from there.

Comment: I know you can edit it in text, just curious what's the difference between projects, some projects can do it, while most cannot. Anyway, just a curiosity, I did the editing in text too.

Answer (score 22):

As @Lex Li has pointed out, VS project properties don't allow you to change the Target Framework, as the project actually targets more than one frameworks.
If, however, you plan to target a single framework, you'll have to change the "TargetFrameworks" tag to "TargetFramework" and specify only one target framework. Then, VS will allow you to select it from Project properties page again.

Comment: Had very similar problem.  Someone using just one framework but I didnt notice an "s" on the end of the TargetFramework element name in the .csproj!

Comment: Not entirely true. All my projects use <TargetFramwork> (singular), but the DD is still disabled. Could it be that <RuntimeIdentifiers> (plural) affects the accessibility of the DD?

Comment: Norgie, did you find a solution? Like, you, my projects are singular and I cannot edit this in VS.

Answer (score 3):

I am using VS2019 and I got the same issue. I used this Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool to fix it. You can download the tool here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135
[image]

Now I am able to see and change my Target Framework.

[image: Now I am able to see and change my Target Framework.]

Answer (score 2):

The two nodes in the project file, TargetFramework and TargetFramework**s** (plural) are the culprits. While it didn't help my project by putting net461;net462 into the latter, I tried renaming the nodes to TargetFramework and entered only net461.

The rename logically also gave me back the enabled combobox and that was what Jan was asking.

I changed it back to TargetFrameworks assuming that the other is now decprecated and resolved the "multiple net version"-error by removing the net462-reference and coded a little replacement. I compile but can only target one net-version.

Answer (score 1):

putting this here as well https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/6180
deleting the global.json file in file explorer (not just from the solution), after restarting vs I was able to change the framework

Comment: Instead of just adding external link, better explain the problem which causes this issue and provide a solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case deleting the **global.json** from everywhere, was the solution and fixed all the projects in the whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

- My application was giving warning like in this picture.

[image: My application was giving warning like in this picture.]

- Also, I was getting an error when I was compiling the application
  like in this picture.

[image: Also, I was getting an error when I was compiling the application like in this picture.]

- I clicked with the right button as in the picture to go to the
  directory where I got the warning message.

[image: I clicked with the right button as in the picture to go to the directory where I got the warning message.]

- The problem was solved by changing the directory names in the
  picture.

[image: The problem was solved by changing the directory names in the picture.]

- After the bugs are fixed, everything looks fine as before.

[image: After the bugs are fixed, everything looks fine as before.]