# Visual Studio 2019 .NET 5.0 framework list is grayed out

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 - 16.8.2 and installing .NET 5.0 SDK - I have noticed that my Target Frtamework dropdown ont he project properties is grayed out.

The screenshot below is for a .NET Core 3.1 console app. Any pointers as to what might be causing this are greatly appreciated.

[image: VS 2019 error]

Comment: this happens when you set [multiple TargetFrameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48352468/1466046) in csproj

Comment: Thanks for the comment,I did look at that previously and unfourtinately this isn't thecause in my case:<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Tracked by [this feedback item](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1269250/target-framework-drop-down-list-on-the-project-pro.html).  Looks like a simple "not yet done" problem btw.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, that item was submitted by me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like uninstalling all of the .NET core SDKs from Add/Remove programs has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. Just installed VS2019 v16.9 preview 1 to bypass the problem and it's ok with this one. The problem still exist with v16.8.2.

16.9 preview 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We tried reinstalling .net core SDK 3.1 and it did not work.

The only thing that's actually working for me is to use the vs installer to repair the vs.
Here's how to make it work using Microsoft docs. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)